# How to create an 'Upload a file' field?

Tags: entities, 8, files

I have a content entity type, and I would like to have an 'Upload file' field. I have declared the field in my Entity class

```
$fields['file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
    ->setLabel(t('Upload a file'))
    ->setDescription(t('Choose file from your computer'));
```

And in EntityForm I am trying to set some settings, because I need to make this dependable later with the '#states'

```
$form['file'] = [
    '#title' => $this->t('File'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Upload a file from your computer'), 
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#default_value' => $entity->file->value,
];
```

But at the moment the field is displayed, but I have problems on saving the form. The file is attached, but not getting uploaded and the error says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in
>   C:\A
>   plus\drupalsite\core\modules\file\src\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\FileValidationConstraintValidator.php
>   on line 18

Comment: In field definition add  ```->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)``` and then in hook update for exmaple load the default form display and configure it. This is for texfield but have a look at upload widget what settings it has: ```$form_display->setComponent('myfield', ['type' => 'text_textarea', 'weight' => -10, 'settings' => ['rows' => 3]]);``` or just do it manually.

Comment: [Set image as permanent in custom block plugin, temporary URI](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222015/set-image-as-permanent-in-custom-block-plugin-temporary-uri). Check this link for uploading an image in Drupal 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $form['File'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Choose  File'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://MyFilesFolder/',
        '#default_value' => $entity->get('File')->value,
        '#description' => t('upload file'),
        '#states' => array(
          'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="File_type"]' => array('value' => t('Upload Your File')),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: The file is uploaded, but not saved, unfortunately :(

Comment: follow this link on how to save @badm[link]http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198135/how-do-i-save-uploaded-file-permanently-in-file-manged-table/198185#198185
do inform me if u need me to add that part here (save permanent part)

Comment: the problem is in this line '#default_value' => $entity->get('File')->value, if i set  '#default_value' => array(10) for exmple it uploads some file with this fid, but how can i get this file__target_id $entity->file__target_id->value doesn't work