# How to Make Managed File Field Available to Twig Template?

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I am wanting to make it so that users can upload images to a block configuration form for a pre-existing (views-generated) block (views_exposed_form) and have the images available in the block's template file. Here's my block class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\exposed_filter_images\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\Block\ViewsExposedFilterBlock;

/**
 * Provides a 'Views Exposed Filter' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "exposed_filter_images_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Exposed Filter Images Block"),
 *   deriver = "Drupal\exposed_filter_images\Plugin\Derivative\ExposedFilterImagesBlock"
 * )
 */
class ExposedFilterImagesBlock extends ViewsExposedFilterBlock {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['image_1'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://images/steps/',
      '#title' => t('Image 1'),
      '#description' => t("Image on the left"),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['image_1'],
      '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['gif png jpg jpeg'],
        'file_validate_size' => [25600000],
      ],
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name="image_type"]' => ['value' => t('Upload New Image(s)')],
        ]
      ]
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['image_1'] = $form_state->getValue('image_1');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $output = parent::build();

    $output['#theme'] = 'views_exposed_form';
    $output['#files'][0] = $this->configuration['image_1'];

    return $output;
  }
}
```

Here's my `exposed_filter_images.module` file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function exposed_filter_images_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
      'views_exposed_form' => [
          'variables' => ['files' => []],
      ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_alter().
 */
function exposed_filter_images_block_alter(&$plugins) {
  if (isset($plugins['views_exposed_filter_block:elder_index-page_1'])) {
    $plugins['views_exposed_filter_block:elder_index-page_1']['class'] = \Drupal\exposed_filter_images\Plugin\Block\ExposedFilterImagesBlock::class;
  }
}
```

And then in the `views-exposed-form.html.twig` file, I can have a number returned with this simple debug: `{{ files.0|json_encode }}` (without the |json_encode filter, nothing shows up), but I'm not really understanding what this number is is or what I can do with it.

So I'm looking for what I would need to do in the class or in the twig file in order to have an image or at least the URL to the image appear on the front-end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since my rep isn't high enough to comment... yet, I have to add my comment as an answer.

My initial thought is that the file would be saved as an entity.  After reading up a bit on some d.o comments, there is/was a bug where managed_files are temporary by default.  Somewhere in the mix you'll need to add something similar to

```
   $image = $form_state->getValue('image');
   $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load( $image[0] );
   $file->setPermanent();
   $file->save();
```

to make the file permanent.
(credit to [This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216107/how-to-use-the-managed-file-field-in-a-custom-form-plugin))

Most likely you will need to save the file itself as an entity in the `blockSubmit` function.

```
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($image_id[0]);
    // Change status to permanent.
    if(gettype($file) == 'object'){
      $file->setPermanent();    
      // Save.
      $file->save();
      $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
      $file->setOwner($user);
    } ... and so on.
```

After that, you should be able to pass the filename or file entity to your theme layer and load it in your preferred method.

Examples modified from [This d.o post](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-02-15/drupal-8-managed_file-upload#comment-10911882)